# Is it possible to combine bayesian SEM with PLS SEM?

Tags: bayesian, structural-equation-modeling, partial-least-squares

I have already read some books about both two structural equation models. It seems both SEMs are suitable to the situation with small observations and large variables.

I assume to use combine both two SEMs to create a more accurate model to analyse the data and structure.